# Looping backwards over EXACT time

Tags: php, loops, time, cron

I have a cron script that checks the status of another application every 30 minutes, (synchronized to: exactly on the hour AND half past the hour). If there is a CHANGE in the status (either 1 or 0) it logs that new status and date and time in a database.
I am now trying to display a bar chart of "statuses within the past 48 hours".

As the database only logs the CHANGE in status, I cannot simply use this data directly with the graph as that will not give me the status for every half hour in the past 48 hours. Instead, I decided to put each database result into an associative array ('12/11/15 - 13:00' => '1', '12/12/15 - 22:30' => '0') and then use a loop that loops backwards by 30 minutes for 48 hours (so 96 times) and checks if a value exists in the array for that time; if it does, then echo that value, otherwise echo the previous value.

```
for ($i=-96; $i <= 0; $i++) {
    $n = $i * 30;
    $d_amount = $n." mins, - 1 month";
    $d_minus = strtotime($d_amount);
    $d1 = date('j/n - h', $d_minus)."h : ".date('i', $d_minus)."m";
    if (isset($chart_availabilityA[$d1])) {
        echo "['".$d1."', ".$chart_availabilityA[$d1]."],";
        $prev_value = $chart_availabilityA[$d1];
    } else {
        echo "['".$d1."', ".$prev_value."],";
    }
 }
```

My issue is: the original script runs exactly on the hour AND half past the hour, but this code snippet only counts back half an hour from whenever the script is run, e.g. '12/11/15 - 13:07' => '1', '12/11/15 - 13:37' => '0', so it doesn't pick up the values from the array.

How do I make code that loops back every exact hour AND exact half past the hour?
Or is there a better way of achieving what I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), a [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) and a [DatePeriod](http://php.net/manual/en/dateperiod.construct.php).

You can create a $start `DateTime` and an $end `DateTime`. For the $start you can use the `setTime` method to set your wanted time. 
In this example you can set the time to 30 minutes or 0 minutes to match your condition (for every exact hour and exact half past the hour). 
From that moment, go back 48 hours. Then create a $dateInterval of 30 minutes. Then create a $datePeriod, which you can loop using a `foreach` and in this example will do so for 97 times (including the start date).

If you want to omit the start date, you can use:

```
$datePeriod = new DatePeriod($start, $dateInterval, $end, DatePeriod::EXCLUDE_START_DATE);
```

For example, using your date '12/11/15 - 13:07' as a start date:

```
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/y - H:i', '12/11/15 - 13:07');
$start
    ->setTime(
        $start->format('H'),
        $start->format('i') > 30 ? 30 : 0
    )
    ->modify('-48 hours');

$end = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/y - H:i', '12/11/15 - 13:07');
$dates = array();
$dateInterval = new DateInterval('PT30M');
$datePeriod = new DatePeriod($start, $dateInterval, $end);

foreach($datePeriod as $date) {
    $d1 = $date->format('m/d/y - H:i');
    array_unshift($dates, $d1);
}

var_dump($dates);
```

will result in:

```
array(97) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "12/11/15 - 13:00"
  [1]=>
  string(16) "12/11/15 - 12:30"
  [2]=>
  string(16) "12/11/15 - 12:00"
etc...
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/FkU50)